# How to use breakpoints for external frameworks in iOS?

Tags: ios, frameworks, breakpoints

In my project we are using external frameworks, now I want to use breakpoints to see data of the external framework. So how could I use breakpoints on external frameworks to see proper values.
Like iOS universal framework.

I have set my breakpoints on external framework for particular method where I have to jump from my main project.But when I am running my project at that time breakpoints is not switching to the framework
Any solution?

Thanks

Comment: i didnt get your question ?

Comment: External framework like UIKit on my project I have abcKit framework, I have framework implementation file,now I have to use breakpoints from main project to abcKit framework. So how could I do this?

Comment: you mean like this http://db-in.com/blog/2011/07/universal-framework-iphone-ios-2-0/

Comment: yes....so now the point is I have to chek my method values of this framework.

Comment: ok ,do u know where you calling this framework methodes?

Comment: ok ,put a break point on that point and use cmd+left click so the corresponding method def will open check there

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32672/discussion-between-nishi-and-navi)